# Fluentbit record_modifier how to remove key with slash?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logging, fluent-bit

I'm trying to remove not interested kubernetes metadata from logs what I'm parsing with fluentbit v. 2.0.5.

After couple of nest filters with lift action, I'm trying to delete keys with slash in name of a key, still see it in elasticsearch

Below filter and json of a log in in elasitcsearch. For example, keys like k8s_pod_id, k8s_docker_id were deleted, but keys with '/' still sthere

`

```
[FILTER]
    Name record_modifier
    Match kube.*
    Remove_key k8s_pod_id
    Remove_key k8s_docker_id
    Remove_key k8s_labels_pod-template-hash
    Remove_key k8s_container_hash
    Remove_key k8s_annotations_checksum/config
    Remove_key k8s_annotations_kubernetes_io/config_source
    Remove_key k8s_annotations_kubernetes_io/psp
    Remove_key k8s_labels_app_kubernetes_io/instance
```

```
{
  "_index": "kube-2022.12.10",
  "_id": "p79h_YQBhdSEPVFK5hZr",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2022-12-10T18:52:41.244Z",
    "level": "info",
    "msg": "kubernetes_sd_configs: added targets: 4, removed targets: 4; total targets: 87",
    "time": "2022-12-10T18:52:41.24443571Z",
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "k8s_pod_name": "victoria-metrics-agent-68b4d79567-4p5jm",
    "k8s_namespace_name": "monitoring",
    "k8s_container_name": "victoria-metrics-agent",
    "k8s_container_image": "victoriametrics/vmagent:v1.81.2",
    "k8s_annotations_checksum/config": "3c9d197fd433243999f2700713e4ab61fc01e056a97ecbfe0f782bbaa931e6a7",
    "k8s_annotations_kubernetes_io/config_seen": "2022-12-07T10:26:57.838470108Z",
    "k8s_annotations_kubernetes_io/config_source": "api",
    "k8s_annotations_kubernetes_io/psp": "eks.privileged",
    "k8s_labels_app_kubernetes_io/instance": "victoria-metrics-agent",
    "k8s_labels_app_kubernetes_io/name": "victoria-metrics-agent"
  },
```

`

I have tried to escape '/' with backslash , also wrap key with qouts

Comment: hey @pluk, did you maybe find the solution for this?